# Why are the array brackets not visible when the formula appears to be executing as expected in excel?

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I have created an index match array formula for a data set in excel and when pressing CSE the formula calculates effectively but the brackets are not visible in the formula bar. If I press f2 on the cell to view the formula and press enter on the cell it becomes #N/A. I would like the brackets to be visible so if anyone else works on this spreadsheet they know they are dealing with an array for that particular calculation.  [image]

Comment: the brackets will not be viewable if the cell is in edit mode.  please provide a photo with the cell selected but not in edit mode that includes the formula bar.

Comment: Added an image, if I click to edit the cell and press enter #N/A is the result